# I keep getting OpenSSL Header Version not found error when compiling OpenSSH Debian Squeeze

Tags: ssh, debian, openssl, debian-squeeze, compilation

I built Openssl1.0.0d `./config shared no-threads zlib`

It installed fine to the default /usr/local/ssl

I went and downloaded OpenSSH 5.8p2 and ran `./configure`

but now it keeps giving me a `Openssl version header not found` error even when I set `--with-ssl-dir=`

I've tried it with arguments `/usr/local/ssl/include` `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl` `/usr/include` `/usr/local/ssl/lib`

I looked in config.log and found `error: openssl/opensslv.h: no such file or directory` which makes little sense since I pointed openssh to where it is store.

`/etc/ld.so.conf`

`include /usr/local/ssl/lib`

I'm at a loss at this point.

Answer (maybe):

Because I am an idiot.

`include /usr/local/ssl/lib` is incorrect.

`/usr/local/ssl/lib` is correct.

It needs to be before the first include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am an idiot.

include `/usr/local/ssl/lib` is incorrect.

`/usr/local/ssl/lib` is correct.

It needs to be before the first `include`.

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me :/

Answer (score 1):

Try `--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl` - your prefix for openssl should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add library to ld.so.conf.d/ directorty like (**filename is VERY important do not change it to something else**)

**$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-openssl.conf**

```
# Openssl 1.1.m for TLSv1.2
/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

And after that as user root run

```sh
ldconfig -v
```

and after that you can issue

```sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ssh --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl  --includedir=/usr/local/ssl/include/
```

only after that you can solve this error.

I have tried it with https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz Portable Openssh source